# Is it possible to turn on Site Collection auditing programmatically using CSOM/JSOM?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I'm creating sites/site collections using CSOM (client code) via an autohosted App. I need to turn on site auditing but can't seem to find any way to do this programmatically.

Any ideas would be welcome!

Comment: I presume from the lack of comments/answers that there is no way to do this using client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Since Audit API is not available neither via the Client Object Model nor SharePoint Web Services, it does not seem possible to accomplish.</strike>

**Update**

In CSOM v. `16.1.3912.1204` was introduced support for Audit management.

Nuget:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM
```

Example

```
//Enable all auditing is site collection level
ctx.Site.Audit.AuditFlags = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AuditMaskType.All;
ctx.Site.Audit.Update();
```

Comment: Looks like the answer is no!

Comment: @Terry Hagan, the answer has changed to yes :)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible now. Thanks to Office DEV Patterns and Practices

Enabling auditing in site collection level

Following code example shows how to enable all auditing setting in site collection level and how to adjust audit log trimming.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Site site = clientContext.Site;
Audit audit = site.Audit;
clientContext.Load(site);
clientContext.Load(audit);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
// Enable all auditing is site collection level
site.Audit.AuditFlags = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AuditMaskType.All;
site.Audit.Update();
// Adjust retention time to be 7 days
site.AuditLogTrimmingRetention = 7;
site.TrimAuditLog = true;
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Disabling auditing in site collection level,
Following code example shows how to disable auditing from site collection level.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Site site = clientContext.Site;
Audit audit = site.Audit;
clientContext.Load(site);
clientContext.Load(audit);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
// Set remove any auditing from site colelction level
site.Audit.AuditFlags = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AuditMaskType.None;
site.Audit.Update();
site.TrimAuditLog = false;
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Source: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/710f9a37ffdffd18acc341f48eff0069fa101d2a/Samples/Core.Settings.Audit/readme.md